# Why do database examples sometimes finish with an add_option call?

Tags: database

Take for an example this perfectly ordinary demo of adding a table. I'm assuming we've all seen examples like this before.

```
function create_table() {
   global $wpdb;
   $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'table_name';

   if( $wpdb->get_var( "show tables like '{$table_name}'" ) != $table_name ) {

       $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . " (
           id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
           col VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
           PRIMARY KEY  (id)
       );";

       require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
       dbDelta( $sql );

       add_option( EmailLog::DB_OPTION_NAME, EmailLog::DB_VERSION );
   }
}
```

What I am puzzled by is this line: `add_option( EmailLog::DB_OPTION_NAME, EmailLog::DB_VERSION );`. The reference page says that add_option adds an option. Gee, I never did guess that would be the case. My sarcasm aside, what is going on with that line? Why is it needed? What exactly does it do?

Answer (score 3):

It’s adding a record in the database of which version of the database is in use. This can be used in future to determine whether or not the database structure on a given site needs to be updated if the plugin changes its database structure in a future version.

You’ve likely seen this yourself when updating WordPress and it tells you you need to upgrade the database. Whenever this happens WordPress records which version of the database is in use so that when WordPress is updated it can see whether an upgrade is required.

Comment: Quick follow up question. Would I (as a plugin writer) use this and if so how?

Comment: Depends on what you’re doing, and the same way, presumably.

Comment: @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt does this answer your question? If so consider marking it as the accepted answer, follow up questions should be asked as new questions